# How to find the minimum value of this expression using AM-GM Inequality?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Consider the following problem:Let $a,b>0$ be real numbers such that $a+b\geq1$. Find the minimum value of the expression $$A=ab+{1\over ab}$$

Now using AM-GM Inequality: $$A=ab+{1\over ab}\geq 2\sqrt{ab\times \frac{1}{ab} }=2$$ However notice that the equality occurs iff $ab=1$ which contradicts the fact that $a+b\geq 1$.How should I rsolve this contradiction? Is there a way to use AM-GM Inequality to solve such kind of problems?

Comment: How does $a b = 1$ contradict $a+b \ge 1\;$?

Comment: Indeed, $ab=1$ in fact implies $a+b>1$ (and hence $a+b\ge 1$) under the given assumptions, since at least one of $a$ or $b$ is at least $1$, and the other is positive.

Comment: @dxiv Can you give a counter example?

Comment: @tatan $a=b=1$ with $a b = 1, a+b=2\ge 1$.

Comment: @dxiv $2>1$ not $\geq$...problem of OP is with the equality...can you counter the equality case?

Comment: @tatan I think you are misreading or misunderstanding something. Please re-read the original question again. Quoted from OP's post: `However notice that the equality occurs iff ab=1 which contradicts the fact that a+b≥1`. My comment just pointed that there is no contradiction (and, by implication, that the minimum value of $A$ is indeed $2$).

Comment: @dxiv Notice that if $ab=1$ then $a+b\geq2$ by AM-GM....this does contradict $a+b\geq1$....shouldn't it be $2$ instead of $1$?

Comment: @tatan $x \ge 2$ does not contradict $x \ge 1$. In fact, it implies it.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks!!!This should solve my and OP's doubt...

Comment: @JackyChong Your $4+\frac{1}{4} \gt 2$ proposed by the OP, so it's not a minimum.

Comment: @JackyChong Please explain what you think is wrong with $a=b=1$.

Comment: @dxiv Ops. You are right.

Comment: I was too focus on $a+b=1$ constraint.

Comment: @JackyChong I suspect that the OP may have actually meant the reverse condition $a+b \le 1$ but s/he didn't followup since.

Answer (score 1):

For $a+b=1$ by AM-GM $$ab+\frac{1}{ab}=ab+16\cdot\frac{1}{16ab}\geq17\sqrt[17]{ab\left(\frac{1}{16ab}\right)^{16}}=17\sqrt[17]{\frac{1}{16^{16}(ab)^{15}}}\geq$$
$$\geq17\sqrt[17]{\frac{1}{16^{16}(\frac{1}{4})^{15}}}=\frac{17}{4}$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$

Id est, the answer is $\frac{17}{4}$.

If $a+b\geq1$ so the answer is $2$ by your AM-GM.

Comment: Yeah this is true if $a+b\leq 1$

Comment: That's creative, but $1 \cdot 1 + \frac {1}{1 \cdot 1} = 2 \lt \frac{17}{4}$. P.S. (after the edit to the answer) Where does $a+b=1$ figure in the question?